# NSIS - Default Installer Width/Height

Tags: height, size, width, default, nsis

i have several setups created with nsis (modernui).
Is there any possibility to change the default width/height of the installer?

Regards and thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 4):

The NSIS UI is actually a main dialog window with a inner dialog where the page content is displayed:

[image: NSIS dialog layout]

If you want to display multiple pages then you pretty much have to accept this design and use a 3rd-party tool like [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to redesign the dialogs. If you want to do this then you should create a copy of "NSIS\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe" and edit it, then use the `ChangeUI` instruction to select the new UI file (`!define MUI_UI yourfile.exe` (and possibly the other MUI_UI_* defines) when using the MUI).

On the other hand, if you are developing a autorun splash screen or something like that then you could resize the inner dialog so it covers the whole outer dialog area.

There is no simple attribute that just sets the desired width and height because all controls on all pages also need to be resized and moved...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tool: [Graphical Installer for NSIS](http://www.graphical-installer.com) (a little self promo :)

This tool is capable of changing dimensions of installer + has a lot of other features like installer skinning and many more.